# Matching all the elements and text excluding one by using XPath

Tags: html, xml, dom, xpath, web-scraping

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="column-items">
    <div>
      abcd
    </div>
    <h2>Thomas</h2>
    <p>Ron</p>
  </div>
  <p>Dave</p>
  Sample text here......
  <b>Andrew</b>
  El murciélago de Bacardí tiene su!!
  <p>abcdef</p>
</div>
```

In the above structure I want the XPath to get all the content including text inside the `<div class="main">` except that I don't want the content of the first div element i.e `<div class="column-items">`.

Comment: Show what you've already tried. Also share exact desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all text nodes from 'main' div excluding text nodes from 'column-items' div, try:

```
//div[@class='main']//text()[not(ancestor::div[@class="column-items"])]
```

Answer (score 1):

The question title asks for *all the elements and text excluding one*, which you go on to say that the first element should be excluded.  If you actually only want text nodes that meet that criteria, see [@JaSON's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63195085/290085).

If you do indeed want ***all the elements*** too, use this XPath:

```
//div[@class='main']/node()[not(self::div[1])]
```

based on position, or this XPath,

```
//div[@class='main']/node()[not(self::div[@class="column-items"])]
```

based upon attribute value.

Comment: Hi Kenneth. What about a `normalize-space()` predicate at the end of your XPath expressions to exclude whitespace nodes ? `//div[@class='main']/node()[not(self::div[1])][normalize-space()]`

Comment: Nothing was said about such a requirement, but perhaps it might help.